Metronome oscillation and a scale?
Metronome oscillation
I have a question. Imagine a board but perfectly balanced on a single rolling point in the middle (for example only one can) and 2 identical metronomes at the two ends (all things like board length, weight distribution and so on equal for the sake of the experiment). If you start them randomly, how would this affect the scale? Will it swing with the two sides going up and down depending on the metronome pendulums affecting the centre of weight? Will it fall on a heavier side, if for example the two pendulums end up pointing right simultaneously? Will it balance eventually when the 2 metronomes sync? ( Very hypothetical experiment but I really need to know).
